# Why does this code yield a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program where the goal is to generate a random three digit number, and have the user make 10 guesses at it. If they guess a correct digit in the correct spot, it is considered a "hit". If they guess a correct digit but it's in the wrong spot, it is considered a "match". For example, if the number to be guessed was 123, and you enter 329, 2 would be a hit and 3 would be a match. My code so far is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MIN 100
#define MAX 999

int main()
{
    //Declare variables
    int userDig1 = 0, userDig2 = 0, userDig3 = 0, randDig1 = 0, randDig2 = 0, randDig3 = 0, guesses = 0;

    //Generate random three digit number
    srand(time(NULL)); //seed
    randDig1 = rand() % ((MAX + 1) - MIN) + MIN; //corresponds to the first digit
    randDig2 = rand() % ((MAX + 1) - MIN) + MIN; //corresponds to the second digit
    randDig3 = rand() % ((MAX+ 1 ) - MIN) + MIN; //corresponds to the third digit

    //A for loop that keeps track of the number of guesses
    for (guesses = 1 ; guesses <= 10 ; guesses++)
    {
        //Store user's guess into the appropriate variables
        printf("Enter guess number %d:\n", guesses);
        scanf("%d%d%d\n", userDig1, userDig2, userDig3);

        //Check the user's digits against the actual digits
        if (userDig1 == randDig1) //if first user digit = first actual digit
        {
            printf("Number %d is a hit!\n", userDig1);
        }
        if (userDig2 == randDig2) //if second user digit = second actual digit
        {
            printf("Number %d is a hit!\n", userDig2);
        }
        if (userDig3 == randDig3) //if third user digit = third actual digit
        {
            printf("Number %d is a hit!\n", userDig3);
        }
        if (userDig1 == randDig1 && userDig2 == randDig2 && userDig3 == randDig3) //if all 3 user digits = all 3 actual digits
        {
            printf("Congratulations, you guessed the number %d%d%d\n", userDig1, userDig2, userDig3);
            break;
        }
        if (userDig1 == randDig2 || userDig1 == randDig3) //if first user digit = second or third actual digit
        {
            printf("Number %d is a match!\n", userDig1);
        }
        if (userDig2 == randDig1 || userDig2 == randDig3) //if second user digit = first or third actual digit
        {
            printf("Number %d is a match!\n", userDig2);
        }
        if (userDig3 == randDig1 || userDig3 == randDig2) //if third user digit = first or second actual digit
        {
            printf("Number %d is a match!\n", userDig3);
        }
        else //if none of the user's digits are matches or hits
        {
            printf("None of the digits you entered are matches or hits. Guess again.\n");
        }
    }

    printf("Game over! You failed to guess the correct number.\n");
}
```

After compiling and running, I get a segmentation fault error after I enter in my first guess.

Now I know *why* segmentation faults occur. It means you are trying to access memory/values that you don't have access to (something along those lines). But in this particular case, I don't understand what would cause this to happen. If I had to venture a guess, I'd say it has something to do with my `scanf` statement, where I'm trying to "extract" the digits by interpreting each digit as a separate integer. I know the mathematical way to extract digits (mod by 10, divide by 10), as I've used this concept in a different program, but not with loop logic. I have tried to use a loop to extract digits here, but I have not yet found a way that works for all numbers. So ultimately, what is my problem here, and what can I do to fix it?

Any and all help is appreciated.

(Additionally, I know I have some bad formatting here, for example the `break` statement being in the middle of all the `if` statements. I will also move this code into a separate function so the user can play again without having to close the program and reopen it).

Answer (score 2):

Because you are passing an integer to `scanf()` where a pointer is expected.

Making a pointer from an integer is undefined behavior, you should pass the address of the values also because they will be modifed by the function, the correct way to use `scanf()` in this situation is

```
if scanf("%d%d%d*%c", &userDig1, &userDig2, &userDig3) == 3)
    input_is_correct();
else
    input_is_bad();
```

Notice that in your case you are passing `0` to `scanf()` and it will attempt to dereference the `(void *) 0x00` or `NULL` perhaps. That is also undefined behavior.

Using a pointer that is not the address of a variable taken with the `&` operator or the return value of `malloc()`/`calloc()`/`realloc()` is in general undefined behavior.

Comment: Wow, I realized what I did right after I posted this. For some reason my eyes couldn't see it in my editor... well at least I found the issue. Thank you for the response!